# Delete duplicate records in MYSQL with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a command that runs every second on node.js It has the function of excluding any duplicate records for a given item, which is specified as in the example by: `AND t1.auction_id = 1335`.

```
DELETE FROM bid_account t1
WHERE t1.id < (Select max(t1.id) FROM bid_account t2 WHERE t1.bidding_price = t2.bidding_price) AND t1.auction_id = 1335;
```

I need it to delete a record that has an equal value in the `bidding_price` column, and keep only one. But it is important that he does this search not across the table, but rather for a certain item as I reported at the beginning, through the column `auction_id`.

I tried to run the above command, but it returns the following error:

```
#1064 - You have a syntax error in your SQL next to 't1
WHERE t1.id < (Select max(t1.id) FROM bid_account t2 WHERE t1.bidding_price ' na linha 1
```

What is wrong with this query?

I use the MYSQL database, and the table `bid_account` has the `id` column as index and primary.

If I use SELECT below, it returns the values in duplicity normally.

```
SELECT bidding_price, count(*) FROM bid_account WHERE `auction_id` = 1335 GROUP BY bidding_price Having Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two quirks from MySQL.  First, when you use an alias for a table, it needs to follow the `DELETE`.  So, this is what you intend:

```
DELETE ba FROM bid_account  ba
WHERE ba.id < (Select max(ba2.id)  -- I assume you want the max from the innter reference
               FROM bid_account ba2
               WHERE ba2.bidding_price = ba.bidding_price
              ) AND
      ba.auction_id = 1335;
```

However, this still will not work, because you are referencing `bid_account` in the table.

So, I think you want something more like this:

```
DELETE ba
    FROM bid_account ba JOIN
         (SELECT ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price, MAX(ba2.id) as max_id  -- I assume you want the max from the innter reference
          FROM bid_account ba2
          WHERE ba2.auction_id = 1335
          GROUP BY ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price
         ) ba2
         ON ba2.auction_id = ba.ba2.auction_id AND
            ba2.bidding_price = ba.bidding_price AND
            ba2.max_id > ba.id
WHERE ba.auction_id = 1335;
```

This still doesn't strike me as useful.  Matching rows based on `bidding_price` seems unusual.  I would expect `auction_id` to be part of the match.  I suspect you want to `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` on both `bidding_price` and `auction_id`.

Comment: My problem is that table `bid_account`  has many records, thousands, so I need something alternate that does not take so long to run, because it will crash if this happens.

Comment: I think that part is wrong, is not it?  `WHERE ba.id <  AND
      ba.auction_id = 1335;`

Comment: @Wendler . . . Thousands of records should not cause this query to crash.

Comment: If I specify the `ba2.auction_id = 1335` within the `SELECT`, do you think the query can get faster?

Comment: @Wendler . . . Yes, that will speed things up.

Comment: `DELETE ba FROM bid_account ba JOIN (SELECT ba2.bidding_price, MAX(ba2.id) as max_id FROM bid_account ba2 WHERE ba2.auction_id = 1335 GROUP BY ba2.bidding_price) ba2 ON ba2.bidding_price = ba.bidding_price AND ba2.max_id > ba.id WHERE ba.auction_id = 1335`

Comment: @Wendler . . . That is sufficient.  I edit the answer.  The logic is a bit more verbose but makes it more obvious that the match on auction id is needed.

Comment: Great, really improved response time. I believe there is something wrong near `ON`. Can you correct the answer?

Comment: @Wendler . . . I'm just curious if there is a reason why you unaccepted this answer.  As the OP you can accept or not accept any answer, but I'm curious.

Comment: Sorry, there is some problem with the site here, because I accept the response to it does not mark as accepted. But I think it worked now. I needed to ask a question with you, I'm having a hard time and the questions are getting very extensive here. You have Skype?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete row by using alias before from keyword in sql query

for example

delete t from test t where t.id = 3

So your query will work fine 
DELETE t1 FROM bid_account t1
WHERE t1.id < (Select max(t1.id) FROM bid_account t2 WHERE t1.bidding_price = t2.bidding_price) AND t1.auction_id = 1335;